# MySQL C++ connector: Execute huge (> 200MB) queries (dumps) with 'mysql_query'

Tags: c++, mysql

I've got a connection (with MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON enabled) and i want to use it to populate a database from a full dump (200 MB) with mysql_query(). (**I don't want to use a mysql cli or something**).

This works well for queries below 100 MB. As soon as the table is half populated the batching process aborts without returning any error, max_allowed_packet is set to 1 GB.

Is it possible to use mysql_query with huge queries or do i need to split it in multiple substeps?

Im running on:

- MariaDB 10.0.14 x64
- Xeon E3, 4x 3.3ghz
- 8 gb ram
- Win 8.1 x64